# Angular Swiper not working when using ngIf

Tags: angular, swiper.js

if i add this line `<ng-container *ngIf="productColor.images">`, the Swiper will not work at all and show no errors in the console. Any idea how to fix this?

```
<swiper *ngIf="productColors" [slidesPerView]="1" [spaceBetween]="50" (swiper)="onSwiper($event)" (slideChange)="onSlideChange()">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let productColor of productColors._embedded.productColors">
      <ng-container *ngIf="productColor.images">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let image of productColor.images._embedded.images">
          <ng-template swiperSlide>
            <img [src]="server.cloudFront + image.url" alt="Oops!" style="max-width: 100%">
          </ng-template>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </swiper>
```

Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-example-j8jxpp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduction example to your code (f.e. via StackBlitz). It's then way easier to help you. Read more about it stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Roy i just added a simple example, please have a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use `swiper.appendSilde(<div class="swiper-slide">content</div>)` which yells out a bunch of `undefined classNames` errors in the console, still works but really annnoying.

When i removed the *ngIf, swiper works fine, but again console log is full of `undefined` error when image url is not loaded from server.

I had to create a field `imagesLoaded = false;` and set it to `true` when all the `image url` were loaded from the sever.

In the template just write:
`<swiper *ngIf="imagesLoaded" ...>...</swiper>`

I don't like it but at least the console is clear now.